# Implementing a Function that Runs Daily in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a Grails web app and would like to pull some data from some API that only allows 1000 calls per IP per day. I would have to make about a million calls to be able to get all the data i need. (all one million users, say).

Therefore, I was thinking of writing a script in Grails that would call that API 1000 times everyday, and in time, my database will be filled.

I only know of threads, but is threads the best way to approach this?

Comment: Yep try quartz, it is easy to setup and it will do the trick for you. :)

Comment: Although at 1000 calls per day it'll take over two and a half years to make a million calls (and by that time there may be another million users who've signed up...).  You might want to consider a different approach that would let you spread the calls across different IP addresses.

Comment: Or see if you can pay to have the limits increased

Comment: What do you mean by writing a scrip in Grails? Anyhow, quartz is what you want here.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) which adds Quartz job scheduling features to Grails applications

[Documentation can be found here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/)